# update firefox to firefoxx 57 on ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: firefox, update-manager

How do I update firefox on ubuntu 16.04 LTS please help

Answer (score 2):

i found a solution

i visited mozilla website and downloaded the latest version of firefox

extracted the .tar.bz2

typed this command in terminal `sudo apt-get remove firefox`

runned the firefox executable

and this solved the problem :)

Comment: You should not need to do this, the latest version of Firefox (57) is available in Ubuntu, you just need to update it through the software updater. Using a version downloaded from Mozilla directly will not get automatic updates with the rest of the system.